# Electron variables defined in renderer are incorrectly available in imported modules

Tags: node.js, electron

I am currently transitioning a script I made in Node.js to Electron. However, I am encountering a problem with variable scope. Variables defined in my Node.js script are not available in my modules unless they are passed or assigned. However, in electron if I declare a variable it will be available in all of my modules without passing or assigning it. For example this Node.js script will correctly fail:

```
// index.js
var myModule = require('./src/myModule.js');
var myString = 'string';
myModule.run();

// myModule.js
exports.run = function() {
    console.log(myString); // Correctly says myString is undefined because it is not declared in myModule.js
}
```

However, the same code in Electron will print the variable defined in `renderer.js`:

```
// renderer.js
var myModule = require('./src/myModule.js');
var myString = 'string';
myModule.run();

// myModule.js
exports.run = function() {
    console.log(myString); // Prints 'string' even though it is not declared in myModule.js
}
```

How can I prevent the variables defined in `renderer.js` from being available in my modules. I find it makes it very easy for me to create unorganized code.

Comment: How are you packaging this? I was surprised that `require` works...It doesn't for me.

Comment: @Codebling Did you make sure `nodeIntegration` was set to `true` when creating your BrowserWindow? By default it is `false`.

Comment: Yup, that works! There are a few different ways to launch electron. I wasn't able to reproduce when just running your script directly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define the type of your script as module in your html.

```
<script type="module" src="./renderer.js"></script>
```

Otherwise renderer.js will use the global scope to save your variable, which is why it was available for myModule.js in your example.

But you can also notice that variables defined in myModules.js will use, like you expect, the local scope. That's because only scripts loaded via the  tag will use the global scope.

So another option to do this would be to create a renderer.js which consists only of

```js
// renderer.js
require('./index.js');
```

and your original nodejs files should work as expected:

```js
// index.js
var myModule = require('./src/myModule.js');
var myString = 'string';
myModule.run();
```

```js
// myModule.js
exports.run = function() {
    console.log(myString); // myString is now undefined
}
```

But you should be aware that variables defined inside of renderer.js will still use the global scope.

Comment: Adding `type="module"` to the script tag gives me the error: `Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.`

Comment: I updated my comment with an option without using type=module. I've used https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start to test this, could you give information on your environment and configurations?

Comment: Nice first answer, Hrun!  Any script loaded through the browser frame has a weird pseudo-`window` module context, resulting in variables being global, but any other modules get wrapped in a isolated (aka "real") module context. Can confirm this worked for me

Comment: Turns out I was also running electron out of date. Updating to electron `8.2.0` fixed the issue of the script not loading. Adding `type="module"` appears to make my code run as expected now. Awarding bounty when SO lets me in 18 hours.